# Wordpress creating new menu always gives error A name is required for this term

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have 2 menus.

1. Main Navigation
2. Footer Navigation

And 3 locations:

1. Top Bar Navigation
2. Main Navigation
3. Footer Navigation

If I try to create a new menu, wp displays **error**

```
A name is required for this term.
```

Obviously I am giving a name in `Menu Name` textbox...
Is this a bug?
Is there a limit to WP menus?
How can I go about adding another menu to use on an existing page as submenu within the page itself?
Thanx

**EDIT 1**
Do I need to add:

```
function register_shop_submenu() {
  register_nav_menu('shop-submenu',__( 'Shop Sub Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shop_submenu' );
```

to `functions.php`?
Is that it??
The admin button option exists in vain??

**EDIT 2**
The code above just added a new location.
While `Manage Locations` tab on `admin panel` now displays:

> Your theme supports 4 menus. Select which menu appears in each
>   location.

Clicking the `use new menu` next to the `drop-down` of this new location yields same error....
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered originally [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277874/creating-menu-always-gives-error-a-name-is-required-for-this-term/279647#279647), I got the same issue and found that the plugin `user-activity-log` was at the origin of the problem.

As I reported [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-create-new-menus-a-name-is-required-for-this-term),the problem is related to the hooks:

- ual_shook_created_term
- ual_shook_edited_term
- ual_shook_delete_term

They return nothing instead of the given term when the taxonomy is ‘nav_menu’.

If you don't use this plugin, check the others plugins that call for example the `pre_insert_term` filter. They should return something.

Comment: thanks. They published update version. I just updated the plugin and the error vanished